# ReviewBoard git post-commit of Git master branch

Tags: git, git-diff, review-board

I have a new git project, and the initial source code is checked in on master. Yes, it probably should have been on a branch, or we should have performed a pre-commit review, but there it is.

ReviewBoard Tools' documentations states that the review range is inclusive, yet when I attempt to post a review using a range of `revFirst...refLatest`, I get a diff between the latest and the first. When performed on the entire master I would expect to see all new files in the review but I see deltas.

The permutations I have tried include:

- `rbt post revFirst..revLatest`
- `rbt post revFirst revLatest`
- `rbt post revFirst^..revLatest`

In these cases the review is not an inclusive range but a diff of revLatest against revFirst.

Is there a way to get RBT to actually do an inclusive diff with Git?

Comment: is revFirst the initial commit in the repository (or any commit that has no parents).  I don't know RBT but it seems a lot of scripts don't handle parentless commits properly.

Comment: Yes it is. I'm trying to get an initial project commmit into ReviewBoard that was done directly into master and I can't seem to get the diff past the initial commit.

Comment: Can you manually create diffs via Git directly and upload them ?